# Ubuntu 18.10 Installation issue

Tags: system-installation

I am using Windows 10 64bit. Now want to install ubuntu alongside it done everything:

1. Converted disk to GPT (Windows was installed on Legacy). Convertion was done using AOMEI Partition Manager Pro 5.8 because windows "win2gpt" was throughing error "disk layout validation failed for disk 0".
2. Turned Off Fast boot and Hibernate
3. In bios set boot mode to UEFI

But during installtion, ubuntu installer throws error "No windows installed".

I have googling for last 5 days but the result is same.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Boot to Windows and run chkdsk.

Answer (score 0):

If all you require is the Ubuntu console (no GUI) you can install the [Ubuntu application](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) in the Windows Store for free and run alongside Windows 10. I use this a lot for work.